# Abrir um Modal com o resultado do MySql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, modal

E ae galera beleza?
Estou estudando Dev Web e to criando um sisteminha pro trampo com cadastro de clientes e relatórios.

Vamos a dúvida. Eu tenho uma página relatório e lá eu tenho um input type="date" dentro de um form que vai fazer a busca a partir de uma data no banco de dados:

```
        <!-- BUSCA CALENDARIO -->        
        <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-4">
        <!-- Input ao qual foi designado a função para exibir o calendário, que vai ser selecionado com jquery na função abaixo. -->
            <input type="date" id="busca_data" name="busca_data" placeholder="data" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-info" id="btn_buscar" type="submit">Buscar</button>
```

O arquivo que mando esse post é o busca_relatorio.php que tem esse codigo:

```
$id_usuario = $_SESSION['id_usuario'];
$empresa_logada = $_SESSION['empresa']; 
$busca_data = $data = str_replace("/", "-", $_POST['busca_data']);

$objDb = new db();
$link = $objDb->conecta_mysql();

$sql = " SELECT DATE_FORMAT(s.data_relatorio, '%d %b %Y') ";
$sql.= " AS data_relatorio_formatada, s.relatorio, u.usuario FROM relatorios AS s JOIN usuarios AS u ON ";
$sql.= " (s.id_usuario = u.id) WHERE nivel = 3 AND s.empresa = '$empresa_logada' ";
$sql.= " ORDER BY data_relatorio DESC ";


$resultado_id = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

if($resultado_id){

    while ($registro = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_id, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){            
        $relatorios = $registro;
        echo '<pre>'.$registro['relatorio'].'</pre>';

    }

} else {
    echo 'Erro na consulta de tweets no banco de dados!';
}
```

Esse echo $registro['relatorio'] foi um teste que eu estava fazendo.

Bom o que eu não tô conseguindo fazer é abrir um Modal dentro da própria página de Relatórios onde venha só esse resultado do banco de dados. Imagino que preciso fazer isso via Ajax porém no meu código nem consegui abrir a modal. Lá eu já tenho criado uma função após o document.ready pra poder carregar esse relatório mas só funciona me levando pra outra página.

O que tenho feito via jquery é isso:

```
$('#btn_buscar').click( function(){                 
                $.ajax({
                    url:'busca_relatorio.php',
                    method: 'post',
                    data: $('#resultado_busca').serialize(),
                    sucess: function(data){                         
                        $('#resultado_busca').val('');
                    }
                });
            });
```

Ai no final da minha página inclui uma div pra mostrar isso:

```
<div class="panel-body" id="resultado_busca"></div>
```

Mas só queria mostrar esse resultado dentro de uma modal. Alguém consegue me ajudar com essa dor de cabeça? kkkkkk

Valeu galera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo que entendi, você está usando Bootstrap, seguindo por esse lado, adicione o seguinte codigo no seu HTML da página onde é carregado o AJAX:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLong" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div id="resultado_busca">...</div>
</div>
```

Dentro do success do seu Ajax adicione:

```
$('#resultado_busca').html(data); // data é o valor printado do lado php
$('#exampleModalLong').modal('show') ; // abre o modal via jquery
```

Só uma observação: success é com dois C's e dois S's

**EDIT**
Esse é a documentação do modal no site do Bootstrap, vale dar uma olhada também: 
https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/modal/

Comment: Valeu cara, realmente esse código já me respondeu o Modal e o erro do success eu nem tinha percebido.

Porém agora preciso fazer a tela ir na requisição via POST, ai ele me leva pra outra página, eu preciso ficar na mesma página e no Modal trazer o resultado. Ou posso criar a busca SQL dentro da própria página. Vou ver como faço agora.

Mas obrigado mesmo Bruno

Comment: Troque o type do button para button, assim ele não será redirecionado para a outra pagina

Comment: Putz, tiro certo era exatamente o que eu precisava. Valeu mesmo Bruno. Um abraço meu caro.